# EL1007E: Property or field 'classes' cannot be found on null - while trying to display name of classes in html

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am trying to get data from multiple tables in Spring Data JPA.

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;


    private String username;

    private String password;

   //Getters and setters generated

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    private List<Classes> classes;
```

**Classes.java**

```
@Entity
public class Classes {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Lob
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "classes", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    private List<User> user;
```

These entities generate table named as 'user_classes' and fields as following classes_id and user_id

I am trying to display name of classes that belong to that particular user.
As I have my models designed as shown above I am trying to do it like this

```
<tr th:each="classes : ${user.classes}">
    <td th:text="${classes.name}"></td>
</tr>
```

My table in database looks like this

[Database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD3RN.png)

So class and user do exist.

But I am facing this error

```
EL1007E: Property or field 'classes' cannot be found on null
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you share your controller or repository

Comment: Looks like there is no "user" object in your model. Or the 'user" is null

Comment: @StanislavL but there is that's why I don't know what is problem :/

Comment: My mindreading skill is not enough to guess where you have error in the code you have not posted. That's why we cannot help you.

Comment: @StanislavL what do you mean by your comment? Code that I am working with is posted. I edited it and added table from database so it's more clear that user and class do exist.

Comment: You're only showing your entities. Where is the controller and your repository that you are using to actually get an instance of User?

Comment: @Plog here is edit.

Comment: You need to pass the `User` object from your controller to the Thymeleaf view.

Comment: That was it! @AbdullahKhan Thank you! :)

Comment: Glad that helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake was in spelling. I have passed User object Thymeleaf view as

```
<tbody th:each="users : ${users}">
```

And I was trying to reach it as

```
<tr th:each="classes : ${user.classes}">
    <td th:text="${classes.name}"></td>
</tr>
```

Where part `${user.classes}` didn't work. When I wrote user object as `users` or like this `${users.classes}` everything worked!